Warning messages by using create-next-app (Windows)
What shall I do with the warning messages:
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm warn deprecated @humanwhocodes/config-array@0.11.14: Use @eslint/config-array instead
npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated @humanwhocodes/object-schema@2.0.3: Use @eslint/object-schema instead

by using npx create-next-app? My package.json:
{
  "name": "boxen2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "next": "14.2.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.5"
  }
}

In the moment I try only npm install, nothing more, because the package.json didn't have the named packages, so it seems, that this package are used from create-next-app. Is that right?

npm ls <package> tells you why a particular thing is installed. But you're (presumably) not a maintainer of any of the packages you're using, so there's not much you can do.
